# BigCommerce OAUTH not sending original temp code

Tags: c#, oauth, bigcommerce

We are developling a BigCommerce app and we've implemented the OAUTH but now that we have uninstalled the app when we attempt to install it again there is no **code** coming back with the original request as outlined in the [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/?_ga=1.231420889.797523064.1474514882#app-installation-and-update-sequence).

```
GET /auth?code=qr6h3thvbvag2ffq&scope=store_v2_orders&context=stores/g5cd38 HTTP/1.1  
Host: app.example.com
```

Just the scope and context (and my own appended parameter) are sent with the GET request.

We depend on this value to be there to be able to perform the OAUTH to get the permanent access token.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

It was working prior to uninstalling the app on my test site.

Comment: Please edit this to remove sensitive information like secrets and codes.

Comment: Thanks but these codes are from the documentation. They are not mine.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else sees this behaviour this is what caused it for me:

I had a #/*target* at the end of my load url in BigCommerce app technical setup.

```
https://www.myserver.com/auth/?myparam=value#/target
```

I removed the #/target and the code comes through. This is obviously a bug on the BigCommerce end. You just have to remember to adjust the return URL in the response to match any changed values in the BigCommerce callback url setup.